# Using Facebook C# SDK - how to post to the wall having the access token

Tags: c#, facebook

Having the access token, how do I post to a Facebook wall. I tried this:

```
var postparameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
postparameters["message"] = message;
postparameters["name"] = "This is a name";
_fbClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
var result = _fbClient.Post("/me/feed", postparameters);
```

But it gives me this exception:

> (OAuthException) Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the blog post *[How-To: Handle expired access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/)*.

> It is very important that your apps handle such situations. If your access token expires, you need to reacquire a valid access token.

Your error is #1 in their list. But the solution is the same for all four reasons.

> **Solution (for all scenarios)**
>
> To ensure the best experience for your users, your app needs to be
>   prepared to catch errors for the above scenarios. The following PHP
>   code shows you how to handle these errors and retrieve a new access
>   token.
>
> When you redirect the user to the auth dialog, the user is not
>   prompted for permissions if the user has already authorized your
>   application. Facebook will return you a valid access token without any
>   user facing dialog. However if the user has de-authorized your
>   application then the user will need to re-authorize your application
>   for you to get the access_token.

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch this exception and renew the access token.

I already answered yesterday on similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384106/facebook-js-php-sdk/9384470#9384470).
Although the answer is in php I hope it will help you